# Woocommerce hook not outputting string

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I cant seem to get hooks working with woocommerce. I'm trying to learn but this piece of code doesn't seem to work and Im not sure why, any ideas ? Thanks.

```
    add_filter ( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'et_filter_link' );

    function et_filter_link ( $content ) {

       $content = '<div class="test-div">Th-th-th-th-th Thats all, folks!</div>';

    return $content;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing return $content to echo $content.

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_before_main_content` isn't a filter, it's an action hook. Therefore you should use `add_action()`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'so_43503969_link' );
function so_43503969_link() {
   echo '<div class="test-div">Th-th-th-th-th Thats all, folks!</div>';
}
```